# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript not triggered second time inside updatepanel

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

My aspx page

```
<span>
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPlayBtn" runat="server" >
  <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:Button runat="server" id="btn" Text="Play" OnClick="btnPlay" />
  </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel> 
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">

 function OpenPlayerWindow() {
     OpenPlayWindow("<%=PlayLink%>");
 }
 function OpenPlayerWindowForError() {
     alert("Please check after sometime. Thanks!")
 }

</script>
```

My CS page

```
protected void btnPlay(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(condition)
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(upPlayBtn, upPlayBtn.GetType(),"tabs", "OpenPlayerWindow();", true);
  }
 else
  {
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(upPlayBtn, upPlayBtn.GetType(), "tabs", "OpenPlayerWindowForError();", true);
  }
}
```

When I click the "Play" button for first time, OpenPlayerWindow() or OpenPlayerWindowForError() opens accoding to the condition. And if I click the button again, "btnPlay" is called but not any of JS function.

If I refresh the page, it works perfect again.

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue by copy pasting your code. I replaced this code OpenPlayWindow("<%=PlayLink%>"); with an alert as I do not know what this method does. It worked fine. Probably there is some issue with this method. Replace it with an alert and then check if it works.

Comment: @samar it did not help. Still same behavior :(

Comment: Looks to me OpenPlayerWindow will get called recursively...can you open up a developer console. And put a console.log statement in there an observe the output...

Comment: @deostroll the JS is not even called on second click though RegisterStarupScript is executed.

Comment: Any error in the developer console?

Comment: @deostroll There is no error in error console of FF

Comment: Sorry I don't have FF. Can you replicate in chrome? If you are debugging in IE you can debug from visual studio. You'll notice stuff happening in the Solution Explorer. Let me know if you can observe the same: http://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Bms.png

Comment: @deostroll http://i.imgur.com/Z7fFJiq.jpg is what I am seeing but this is same even for first click.

Comment: Hi, can you try `ScriptManager.RegisterScriptBlock` instead of `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`

Answer (score 0):

```
<span>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPlayBtn" runat="server" >
<ContentTemplate>
  <asp:Button runat="server" id="btn" Text="Play" OnClick="btnPlay" />

   <script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenPlayerWindow() {
     OpenPlayWindow("<%=PlayLink%>");
    }
    function OpenPlayerWindowForError() {
     alert("Please check after sometime. Thanks!")
    }
   </script>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel> 
</span>
```

Comment: Still it behaves like I mentioned in question!

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to write this code in comments hence I am writing this as an answer. The following is the code which I have with me. **Please copy-paste it in a separate project and try if it works.**

Also if I am not replicating this issue properly(not written the code correctly) then please comment.

If the code is okay with you and if it works on a separate project then there probably is a problem in some other code which is not shown in your question.

**aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Practice_Web.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <span>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPlayBtn" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" Text="Play" OnClick="btnPlay" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </span>
        <%--It works if I keep the script here also--%>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function OpenPlayerWindow() {
        alert("Thanks!");
    }
    function OpenPlayerWindowForError() {
        alert("Please check after sometime. Thanks!");
    }
</script>
</html>
```

**aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Practice_Web
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //This is just to simulate the condition part of the original code
            if (Session["condition"] == null)
                Session["condition"] = false;
            else
                Session["condition"] = !Convert.ToBoolean(Session["condition"]);
        }

        protected void btnPlay(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool condition = Convert.ToBoolean(Session["condition"]);
            if (condition)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(upPlayBtn, upPlayBtn.GetType(), "tabs", "OpenPlayerWindow();", true);
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(upPlayBtn, upPlayBtn.GetType(), "tabs", "OpenPlayerWindowForError();", true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
protected void btnPlay(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(condition)
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),"tabs", "OpenPlayerWindow();", true);
  }
 else
  {
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "tabs", "OpenPlayerWindowForError();", true);
  }
}
```